# Condition for representation to be surjective?

Tags: representation-theory

I consider the representation $\rho:\mathcal{A}\to\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal{H})$ of a $C^*$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$ as operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Is there a simple condition to check if the representation is surjective, i.e., if we have for any operator $\hat{A}:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ and algebra element $A\in\mathcal{A}$, such that $\rho(A)=\hat{A}$.

I'm particularly interested in the representations of Clifford and Weyl algebras.

*In physics language, this should come down to the question if any operator of a bosonic or fermionic system can be expressed as a power series in creation and annihilation operators.*